# Vaadin Session and Spring Security Authentication object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin8

I have implemented Spring Boot/Vaadin 8 application which uses Spring Security in order to authenticate and authorize the user. I use usual Thymeleaf/HTML template for my login form(not Vaadin UI).

Right now inside of Vaadin application I'm able to reach the authenticated user in a standard following Spring way:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

On the other hand, there is another, purely Vaadin mechanism:

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent()
```

I have a question, do I need to place in some way the Spring `Authentication` object to `VaadinSession` or it is okay to use both of these approaches separately and just invoke `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` inside of Vaadin application where needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to place `Authentication` inside the `VaadinSession`.

Basically Spring Security wraps your Vaadin Application behind a Login. For the Vaadin Application itself it more or less doesn't matter.

If you wan't to add permissions for view access you can use your own implementation of `ViewAccessControl` to check if an authenticated user has the required permissions to access a certain view.

Comment: where is ViewAccessControl in vaadin 10 ?